# Laravel 5.5 - Polymorphic relationships

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have four tables (models) in Laravel:

**User.php**

```
id - integer
name - string
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'token_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function embeds()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\Role');
    }
}
```

**UserRoles.php**

```
id - integer
user_id - integer
role_id - integer
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserRoles extends Pivot
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Role.php**

```
id - integer
name - string
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * Don't auto-apply mass assignment protection.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserRoles::class);
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
id - integer
title - string
body - text
role_id - integer
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Don't auto-apply mass assignment protection.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

As you can see, a `UserRoles` is a pivot table to connect `Users` with `Roles`. And `Posts` can only be associated with one role (tech spec req).

How would make the  relationships in Eloquent make it so I can have a user get every single `Post` they can see through the `Roles` they are assigned?

I have revised looking through the Laravel Relationships documentation and I have seen `Many-to-Many` polymorphic relationships but it seems I keep getting: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table` or some sort.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your models? precisely, how do you define the relationships

Comment: @Hamoud Done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a pivot table does need a model. You need four tables and three Models.

You almost got the tables right. Just rename the `UserRole` table to `role_user` to follow [Laravel convention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

> The role_user table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the user_id and role_id columns.

And here is how you should set up the models:

```
// User.php

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Post::class, Role::class);
    }

// Role.php

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

Comment: The table is `user_roles` and the model is `UserRoles`, so... the model should be `RoleUser` and db_table be `role_user`?

Comment: And I get `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mangsysd.user_role' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `user_role` where `user_id` = 1 limit 1)`

Comment: I get `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `posts`.*, `roles`.`user_id` from `posts` inner join `roles` on `roles`.`id` = `posts`.`role_id` where `roles`.`user_id` = 1)` following your post.